# FB Open Graph, Multiple (2) objects, per action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm looking at posting to open Graph.

I have a user action linking to two objects, much like Spotify does,
`User` `[LISTENS]` to `[SONG OBJECT]`, `[ARTIST OBJECT]` on `[SPOTIFY]`

I have `User` `[ATE]` a `[PACK OF CRISPS OBJECT]` at `[VENUE OBJECT]` on `[APP]`

I cannot find anywhere you can do this, is it because Spotify are special partners?

I want to use my own `Venue` Object, rather than a FB `Checkin/Venue` object as I'm not using FB for the Venue lookup within the app, and don't know how I would link them.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you ever figure this out on your own? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: no - but i'm sure it is now possible now they have opened up the Graph API - but haven't checked back.